# Permisions overwritten when files are transferred via FTP. What to do?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-httpd, ftp, vsftpd

Got my web server up and running using apache2 with the ability to ftp to `/var/www` folder.  However, if I make an update to `.html` and copied over the file via ftp, the file's permissions become more restrictive such that apache produces an error to the web client that file is not readable because of insufficient permissions (or something to that effect).  I then have to `ssh` in and modify the permissions to the associated files (`sudo chmod 755 *`) while in `/var/www`.

Is there an easier to do this?

Comment: What are the exact permissions? As which user are you logging to ftp?

Comment: I don't have access as of now, but the I created the user `ftpuser` and added it to the `www-data` group where `www-data` has ownership of `/var/www`.  I'll report the resulting permisions when I get the chance.

Comment: May be your ftp server is configured to force more restrictive premissions. Check it too if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have few options:

1. Set `local_umask` in `vsftpd.conf` to 022 instead of default 077
2. Set `chmod_enable` to `YES` and do CHMOD via ftp client (if it does not do so already)

By the way, better to use `scp`, because it does not transmits your credentials in plaintext, and you can configure public key authentication, so you will not have to enter password each time, but I'm not sure about how it sets permissions on uploaded files.

Comment: This may be sad, but I didn't know about `scp`.  Going to look into it!